# Go interface for set of constraints and inheritance

Tags: inheritance, interface, go

I am still trying to understand Golang interface. Please correct me and help me understand.

Frances Campoy explains, `interface` is a set of contraints.

So in my case, let's say I have one `Store` interface that is to be interfaced with contrains, like sort `Interface` in Go.

```
type Store interface {
    Earning() int
    Expense() int
}
```

Then what do I have to do if I want to implement this interface constraint to other packages like `StoreA`, `StoreB`? I want to get a message like when I try:

```
aa := StoreC{}
aa.Add("AAA")
// error saying `StoreC` does not implement method `Add`, constrained by interface `Store`... something
```

So what do I do if I want to enforce this contraint in other `Store`s? Do I need to do something like inheritance?

```
type StoreC interface {
    Store
}
```

In other words, I wonder how `package sort`'s interface of 3 methods can be enforced to every `sort` operations in Go. How does it enforce the contraints to any other possible `sort` uses in Go?

Thanks!

Comment: Just have to use every `struct` that you want to be a `Store` as a `Store` in a method call or somewhere. You usually do that in the ordinary course of coding--if you don't, because you're passing it around as an `interface{}` say, consider changing that. If you need to force a certain struct to be used as a certain interface type, do `var _ = iFace((*structType)(nil))` at the toplevel.

Comment: Thanks! Then what would be the scope of the constraints?

Comment: I mean does the constraint apply to other packages? If not how i do it to other packages

Comment: I think you're looking for something like an explicit, declared "implements" relationship, and, syntactically, Go doesn't have that. Interface constraints only get enforced when a type is used. The `var _` trick is just a way you might be able to force a type to be used if your code doesn't otherwise use it yet. Try it out--hope this helps.

Comment: It may be worth noting that APIs that take in a one-method `interface` could be re-written as taking a function type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63557675/12817546.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface is mostly useful for a user of the interface. By looking at what methods the interface provides, you know what methods you can safely use.

If you have an interface:

```
type MyInterface interface {
   Frob(int)
   Flanged() bool
}
```

You know that any function `func foo(thing MyInterface)` can safely call `thing.Frob(..)` and `thing.Flanged()` safely.

Any type that implements both a `func (r a_type) Frob(int)` and `func (r a_type) Flanged() bool` will satisfy the interface. The compiler will do this check at compile-time.

Defining a method looks (roughly) like this:

```
func (reciever a_type) methodname (possibly more args here) possibly_a_return_type {...}
```

The receiver's type is the type for which the method is defined. The name of the method comes between and then there's the (possibly empty) argument list.

Comment: Thanks! Then where is the `any type`? Does it have to be in the same package? It's not since we have `sort` Interface globally in Go that has to implement Less, len,... methods for sorting. So let's say I want to implement my own interface then what would be the scope of this interface to be applied... Thanks!

Comment: @cvxv31431asdas I am not sure I understand your question. If you want a type you have defined to implement an interface, you simply implement the required methods 9and suddenly it satisfies the interface). If you want to define an interface, you tell the compiler what methods are needed.